# Rails: Selecting all records that are unique by a specific column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Recommendation model and I would like to select all recommendations that are distinct by their movie_id column. I've tried a few methods but none that have worked yet:

```
scope :not_duplicate, -> {
    group_by(&:movie_id)
  }

==> doesn't work on a class

scope :not_duplicate, -> {
        uniq_by(&:movie_id)
      }

==> doesn't work on a class

scope :not_duplicate, -> {
        select(:movie_id).group(:movie_id, "recommendations.id")
      }

==> only returns movie_id values and I need entire record

scope :not_duplicate, -> {
        select("recommendations.*").group(:movie_id)
      }

==> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "recommendations.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I'm sure this is a pretty regular occurrence but for some reason I can't find the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to clarify what you're looking for more. Are you wanting just the first recommendation per movie? If so, try, `Recommendation.joins("JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) as first_id FROM recommendations GROUP BY movie_id) t ON t.first_id = recommendations.id")`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could try this

```
Recommendation.select {|rec| rec.movie_id == movie_id).uniq
```

Comment: I'm sure you don't want to do this, effeciency-wise!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
scope :not_duplicate, -> {
        group(:id, :movie_id).distinct
      }
```